# How can I export a model using the CAT bone system into XNA?

Tags: xna, 3d, 3dsmax

Has anyone successfully used the CAT bone system in 3ds Max and exported the file into XNA? If so, what was your method of doing so?

There are a number of methods of doing this, apparently, but the ones I've tried have not worked.

I used the Panda Exporter which creates an `.X` file. This seems to be the latest way of going about this, but when it's loaded in XNA, there is an error saying something about the bone weights. This happens when I export with and without CAT bones.

Comment: Dont use Panda, I've had major problems exporting through it aswell.
I've had most success kw-export so I'd recommend that, even though it also has its limitations.

Comment: Have you tried FBX?

Comment: have you tried baking the animation to keyframes ? and as above said FBX